# the difference between using useRef and directly using watch function

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm making a register form with react-hook-form.
I use useRef to compare "password" and "password_confirm".
I know that useRef is used to variable commonly. and the lecture that I heard let me this way.

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  const password = useRef();
  password.current = watch("password");

<input
          name="password"
          type="password"
          {...register("password", { required: true, minLength: 6 })}
        />

 <input
          name="password_confirm"
          type="password"
          {...register("password_confirm", {
            required: true,
            validate: (value) => value === password.current,
          })}
        />
```

this way is using useRef for containing current value of "password" input.
so then, password.current validated with value of "password_confirm" input .
however, I think "Why should I use useRef?"
Because, I can make validation in this way.

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

<input
          name="password"
          type="password"
          {...register("password", { required: true, minLength: 6 })}
        />

 <input
          name="password_confirm"
          type="password"
          {...register("password_confirm", {
            required: true,
            validate: (value) => value === watch("password"),
          })}
        />
```

I'm curious that the difference between the way using useRef hook and the another way directly using watch function.

Comment: Using a `ref` here does not make any sense, you're only creating a extra variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ref` like this might help you to solve some closure problems.

But not with the code you provided, here it is not necessary.

Also it is better for your case to use `getValues` instead of `watch`, you don't need those extra rerenders.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is that when using `useRef` you store the value returned from `watch("password")` into the `ref` and then read it from there, it's just an extra redundant variable.